# can't the get signConfig for this build

Tags: android

can't the get signConfig for this build
[image]

Comment: Please provide the gradle build file (in a complete, verifiable and minimal example)

Answer (score 0):

Hard to help you too much with only this information to go on. But I'd advise adding a signing configuration to your configuration for this build option in your grade file: developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing#gradle-sign If you prefer, you can also go to Build -> Generate Signed APK and you can choose your signing configuration (or generate it) when you're there.